# Export to .ppt file using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Powerpoint is very slow

Tags: c#

I have a dashboard application and I need to export all its tabs (around 30 chart images and data tables) into powerpoint file. I am using "Microsoft.Office.Interop.powerpoint" assembly. This is working fine but it is taking too much time around 5 minutes. I have to export the file within 30 seconds. Can it be possible? Is there any other API which runs faster than this. I have heard about open XML but never used. Can it be useful here. I also have used parallel in C# but that is not giving proper result. 
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the answer and it is OPEN XML. It runs much faster than Interop.